# jQuery UI 1.8 autocomplete - how to detect change selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have a jQuery autocomplete control. On selection the value is stored in a label. If the user then goes back to the autocomplete and changes selection, ideally I would want to clear the value in the label and populate it only when new selection is made. I tried using change event but it fires each time a selection is made.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the .select-event?

From the demo page, http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select :

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

It should be triggered once you actually select something, unlike the change event.

Comment: select is fine, but then if the user goes back and starts changing his selection by typing into the autocomplete box, how do i find out user has started changing stuff and I need to disable a button below in the UI.

Comment: Have you tried capturing and storing the value on blur() and then on keypress() compare the two values and if != then label.disable() Sorry i m talking in codenglish...

Answer (score 0):

Clear the field on focus then blur on select because the autocomplete automatically focuses on select.

```
 $("#searchInput").focus(function(){
   $(this).val("");
});

$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
    source: source,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#searchInput").blur();

    }
});
```

[js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HwUG7/)